# MySql pattern matching

Tags: mysql, regex, pattern-matching

I need a MySQL pattern to match a number, followed by a question mark.
I need something like
**... like '%[0-9]?%'**
but I have no idea how to create this regular expression.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html does not help.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a column of type text. I have to find some records in it.
I have tried SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%[0-9]?%';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%^[0-9]?$%' and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
select * from table
where field rlike '[0-9]\\?'
```

Remember to escape the question mark. Otherwise, it will make the number optional.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html).

Comment: Thank you. This works just fine. I'll also take a look at the rlike syntax.

Answer (score 4):

you could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourField REGEXP '[0-9]\\?'
```

That will return rows where `YourField` contains a number followed by a `?` anywhere in the value.

If you want it to only match if the whole field is a number followed by a `?`. I.e. `9?` then you could use this regex instead:

```
^[0-9]\\?$
```

Comment: This does not escape the ?-sign

Comment: @ДамянСтанчев your right, i totally forgot about escaping, i've corrected it.